# Scheme error says "attempt to apply non-procedure" when flipping tuples in a list

Tags: runtime-error, scheme, chez-scheme

I'm working through a textbook on programming languages, and one of the exercises was to make a function in Scheme that flips tuples in a list. Here's my code:

```
; invert : Listof(List(Int,Int)) -> Listof(List(Int,int))
; usage: (invert '((a 1) (a 2) (1 b) (2 b))) -> ((1 a) (2 a) (b 1) (b 2))
(define invert
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons
        (flip (car lst))
        (invert (cdr lst))))))
; flip : List(Int,Int) -> List(Int,int)
; usage: (flip '(a 1)) -> (1 a)
(define flip
  (lambda (tuple)
    (if (not (eqv? (length (tuple)) 2))
      (eopl:error 'flip
        "Tuple is not length 2~%")
      (cons (cdr tuple) (car tuple)))))
```

I tried testing my program in chez-scheme. When I use the test case in the usage comment, I get this error: `Exception: attempt to apply non-procedure (a 1)`. I've never worked with Scheme before, so I'd greatly appreciate any help and advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a coupe of errors in `flip`, this should fix them:

```
(define flip
  (lambda (tuple)
    (if (not (= (length tuple) 2))
        (eopl:error 'flip "Tuple is not length 2~%")
        (list (cadr tuple) (car tuple)))))
```

In particular:

- The specific error reported was because of this expression: `(tuple)`. We must not surround variables with `()`, *unless* they're procedures that we intend to call.
- We should use `=` for comparing numbers, not `eqv?`.
- In this expression: `(cons (cdr tuple) (car tuple))` there are two issues, for building a *list* of two elements we use `list`, not `cons`. And for accessing the second element we use `cadr`, not `cdr` - you should read a bit about how `cons`, `car` and `cdr` are used for building lists.

Notice that there's a simpler way to solve this problem if we use `map`; I'll skip error checking for simplicity:

```
(define (invert lst)
  (map (lambda (tuple) (list (cadr tuple) (car tuple)))
       lst))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate the explanation and the simpler solution. Is it best to try to use map instead of building a list whenever possible?

Comment: Yes indeed! in functional programming we try very hard to reuse existing list procedures whenever possible, and there are lots of them already built-in, to make your life easy.